# Deleting a community wiki answer to repost it as a normal post?

Tags: support, deletion, community-wiki

I have accidentally tapped on the community wiki button in one of my answers. I want it to be deleted and I will repost the answer. The link to that answer is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774071/egmo-2015-p5-let-m-n-be-positive-integers-with-m-1-anastasia-partitions/3774100#3774100)

Comment: I undid the CW now.

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer there is no need to delete an answer when you accidentally turned it into CW. Moderators can change it back to a normal post.

All you need to do is get our attention. The best way to do this for things like that is to raise a flag "in need of moderator intervention" on the post and to briefly explain the issue.

Except for unusual circumstances, we will follow the request and revert back the CW.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thank @quid

Comment: You are welcome. Generally if you want our attention for a particular post  the simplest is to flag. (It sometimes can  take slightly longer to get it handled but on average works more smoothly.)

Comment: When a post is un-CW-ed, what happens with rep. points? Does the user gain rep. for any votes submitted when the post was CW, or are these votes ignored?

Comment: @user1729 they gain the points retroactively (contrary to the inverse action). In  principle this might create a risk of trying to  game the system, but in practice I don't think it is an issue. Most users are honest and most of the not so honest ones will be smart enough not to game in a way that must explicitly involve a mod-action to work. If we suspect something odd we might just not follow the request and possibly do more if it seem egregious.

Answer (score 3):

Flag it for the moderators and ask them to convert it back from community wiki.